# Informix SQL merging/joining and updating a table

Tags: sql, informix

I have an Informix database.

```
EMPLOYEE 
LAST_NAME  FIRST_NAME  SSN
----------------------------------------------
SMITH      JOHN        123456789                                                         
DOE        JANE        987654321                                                      
SMITH      JOHN        5555555     

SCHEDULE
SSN        START   END
---------------------------
123456789  8:00AM  4:00PM
987654321  8:00AM  4:00PM
```

I need to take the profile John Smith with ssn 5555555 and replace it with the other John Smith with ssn 123456789. Also with this query I need to update the Schedule table to update to with the new ssn 5555555.

The most important thing is that the profile with ssn 123456789 is now attached to the schedule table with the ssn 5555555. Then I need to be able to delete the old employee with ssn 123456789.

Comment: Post the detailed layout and the names of all tables, profile, "duplicate", and "schedule" involved so people can help you

Comment: Using SSN to connect things isn't a very good idea.  All else apart, it makes sensitive data a key part (pun intended) of the database schema, rather than a field tucked out of the way that can be given severely restricted access permissions.   You might want to consult with your legal team about the whether what you're doing is safe enough.  Gut feel: it ain't.

Comment: Which 7 digits of the 9 digit SSN should be used in the duplicate profile?  How is the schedule table affected?  How big are the tables — number of rows?  Unless they're in the millions (which would be unusual for a list of employees, even with massive turnover — most organizations aren't that big), then you'll probably use a few SQL statements (2, 3?).  However, we need the schema for the tables (or a relevant subset of the schema) and directions on which 7 of the 9 SSN digits are to be used. What happens if two people share the same 7-digit 'SSN'? Do you know about violations tables? (MCVE])

Comment: Also, please include version information for the Informix database, and platform information.   You can use `SELECT DBINFO('version', 'full') FROM "informix".systables WHERE tabid = 1` — for my (somewhat out of date) server, that reports `IBM Informix Dynamic Server Version 12.10.FC5`, running on macOS Sierra 10.12.5.  If the SQL doesn't work, then it probably means that you're running a very old version of Informix indeed.

Comment: So yes its a very old system, was there prior to when I started. so what happen was that someone years ago forgot to turn off a line where SSN is shown on the application (PCI issue for sure). Once I turn that feature off, then comes in  a duplicate profile with the 7 digits for ssn (its really the employee number). I need to get rid of the employee with the ssn which is easy BUT i need to move the schedules attach to the user with the employee number.

Comment: Because you didn't prefix your comment with `@Jonathan` or similar, I didn't see your response until just now.  You've not identified the version of Informix or the platform on which it is running.  You've not shown the tables that need to be manipulated.  I'm sorry, but we can't work in the vacuum you've provided.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry about that. heres the info IBM/Informix-Client SDK Version 3.00.UC3
Copyright (C) 1991-2007 IBM

Comment: Thank for the information about the CSDK.  That suggests you are using Informix IDS 11.10, which is out of service.  Maybe you should show the query that does the job one at a time?  It's proving very hard to get any useful information out of you — which makes it impossible to get any useful information back to you.  I think I'll take up dentistry for chickens — teeth-extraction a speciality.   There simply isn't enough information in the question to be able to help you.

Comment: I am sorry, it would be easier to screenshot or copy but its sensitive information. EX employee profile John Doe has ssn 123456789 which is connected to a schedule table using the ssn number. I have another profile with is the same person John Doe with everything is the same expect there ssn is 1234567. I need to make remove the profile with ssn 123456789 and replace it with profile ssn 1234567 BUT i also need to update the schedule table to now replace the ssn 123456789 with ssn 1234567. I can do a simple update to the schedule table

Comment: but when I need to do an entire employee profile more than 1000 people it will be tiresome to do one by one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler sorry if I am coming off short on information.

Comment: If you're going to ask many questions on SO, you need to learn how to make information-equivalent tables that are sufficiently similar to your actual problem but which don't reveal anything confidential. For example, `CREATE TABLE EmployeeProfile(EmpID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, EmpName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL {, …})`, and `CREATE TABLE DuplicateProfile(EmpID CHAR(7) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, EmpName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL {, …})`, and `CREATE TABLE EmpSchedule(EmpID VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL, WorkStart DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE NOT NULL, WorkStop DATETIME YEAR TO MINUTE, TaskName VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)`.

Comment: Now, how many of the `EmpID` types are correct and how many incorrect (there are three different types shown; it is unlikely you're silly enough to that many different types for one field).  Note that the handling for INTEGER is different from the handling for CHAR. Can you show some sample data (2-5 rows in the EmployeeProfile table, 5-10 rows in the EmpSchedule table?  Presumably, the DuplicateProfile table starts out empty and is filled up by the operation you're asking about.  You should show the desired output in the DuplicateProfile and EmpSchedule tables as well as the input values.

Comment: Have you already validated that there are no employees that share the same 7-digit prefix for their SSNs?  If not, you'll have unhappy people when you combine their schedules and profiles.  What will you do if you ever end up with two employees with the same 7-digit prefix to their SSNs?  (And I think you should move to a system-generated number completely divorced from the SSN — ASAP to limit your liability.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I agree with your statement......the 7 digit ssn is unique. the 7 digits is really there employee id which is generated by another system. there will be no other employee using that number. As of right now this database is at end of life, will only be around another 36 months or so tops. I am trying to maintain it and do the upkeep in the meantime.

Comment: I am going to make a sample data and update this thread tomorrow. thanks for all your patience so far. I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you. I've laid it out a bit better. I'm now puzzled that the text refers to SSN 55555 (five 5's), but the data contains 5555555 (seven 5's) — is this a typo or a different employee? I also note you've not stated the type of the SSN column — character or number.  It's important, believe it or not.  And it isn't clear at the moment what you want (you say you want to take 55555 and replace it with 123456789, but then you want to remove 123456789). You may need a mapping table to map old SSN to new SSN since there isn't an obvious tranformation between 12456789 and either 55555 or 5555555.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes its a typo, it should be 7 5's. (5555555) the ssn column is INTEGER.

Answer (score 0):

An original version of the question seemed to discuss truncating a 9-digit SSN into a 7-digit not-quite-SSN.  The revised mapping of 123456789 ⟶ 5555555 is not one that can be done algorithmically.  The original question also discussed dealing with multiple mappings, though the example data only shows and describes one.

I'm assuming that the Employee table does not yet have the 7-digit SSN for John Smith, even though the sample data shows that.

There are multiple ways to address the requirements.  This is one way to do it.

To address the generalized mapping, we can define an appropriate temporary table and populate it with the relevant data:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE SSN_map
(
    SSN_9    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    SSN_7    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO SSN_map(SSN_9, SSN_7) VALUES(123456789, 5555555);
-- …
```

This table might need to be a 'regular' table if it will take time to get its content correct.  This would allow multiple sessions to get the mapping done correctly.

If there is an algorithmic mapping between the 9-digit and 7-digit SSNs, you could still create the SSN_map table applying the algorithm to the SSN_9 (SSN) value to create the mapping.  You might also be able to apply the algorithm 'on the fly' and avoid the mapping table, but it makes the UPDATE statement harder to get right.

Assuming the database supports transactions (Informix databases can be logged, meaning 'with transactions', or unlogged, meaning 'without transactions'), then:

```
BEGIN WORK;

-- Create 7-digit SSN entry corresponding to 9-digit SSN
INSERT INTO Employee(SSN, Last_Name, First_Name)
    SELECT m.SSN_7, e.Last_Name, e.First_Name -- , other employee columns
      FROM Employee AS e
      JOIN SSN_map  AS m ON e.SSN = m.SSN_9;
```

Some (older) versions of Informix won't let you SELECT from the table you are modifying as shown.  If that's a problem, then use:

```
SELECT m.SSN_7, e.Last_Name, e.First_Name -- , other employee columns
  FROM Employee AS e
  JOIN SSN_map  AS m ON e.SSN = m.SSN_9
  INTO TEMP mapped_emp WITH NO LOG;
INSERT INTO Employee SELECT * FROM mapped_emp;
DROP TABLE mapped_emp;
```

Continuing: the Employee table now contains two entries for each mapped employee, one with the old 9-digit SSN, one with the new 7-digit not-quite-SSN.

```
UPDATE Schedule
   SET SSN = (SELECT SSN_7 FROM SSN_map WHERE SSN_9 = SSN)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SSN_map WHERE SSN_9 = SSN);
```

This updates the Schedule with the new not-quite-SSN value.  The WHERE EXISTS clause is there to ensure that only rows with an entry in the SSN mapping table are changed.  If it was not present, any unmatched row would have the SSN set to NULL, which won't be good.

```
DELETE FROM Employee
 WHERE SSN IN (SELECT SSN_9 FROM SSN_map);

COMMIT WORK;
```

This deletes the old data with 9-digit SSNs from the Employee table.  You could drop the SSN_map table at this point too.

#### Complete test script

```
-- Outside the test, the Employee and Schedule tables would exist
-- and be fully loaded with data before running this script
BEGIN WORK;

CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE 
(
    LAST_NAME   CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    FIRST_NAME  CHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    SSN         INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO Employee(Last_Name, First_Name, SSN) VALUES('SMITH', 'JOHN', 123456789);
INSERT INTO Employee(Last_name, First_Name, SSN) VALUES('DOE', 'JANE', 987654321);

CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE
(
    SSN         INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employee,
    START       DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE NOT NULL,
    END         DATETIME HOUR TO MINUTE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(SSN, START)
);
INSERT INTO Schedule(SSN, Start, End) VALUES(123456789, '08:00', '16:00');
INSERT INTO Schedule(SSN, Start, End) VALUES(987654321, '08:00', '16:00');

SELECT * FROM Employee;
SELECT * FROM Schedule;

-- Start the work for mapping SSN to not-quite-SSN
CREATE TEMP TABLE SSN_map
(
    SSN_9    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    SSN_7    INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
INSERT INTO SSN_map(SSN_9, SSN_7) VALUES(123456789, 5555555);

-- In the production environment, this is where you'd start the transaction
--BEGIN WORK;

-- Create 7-digit SSN entry corresponding to 9-digit SSN
INSERT INTO Employee(SSN, Last_Name, First_Name)
    SELECT m.SSN_7, e.Last_Name, e.First_Name -- , other employee columns
      FROM Employee AS e
      JOIN SSN_map  AS m ON e.SSN = m.SSN_9;

UPDATE Schedule
   SET SSN = (SELECT SSN_7 FROM SSN_map WHERE SSN_9 = SSN)
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SSN_map WHERE SSN_9 = SSN);

DELETE FROM Employee
 WHERE SSN IN (SELECT SSN_9 FROM SSN_map);

SELECT * FROM Employee;
SELECT * FROM Schedule;

-- When satisfied, you'd use COMMIT WORK instead of ROLLBACK WORK
ROLLBACK WORK;
--COMMIT WORK;
```

#### Sample output

The first four lines are the 'before' data; the last four are the 'after' data.

```
SMITH           JOHN              123456789
DOE             JANE              987654321

  123456789 08:00 16:00
  987654321 08:00 16:00

DOE             JANE              987654321
SMITH           JOHN                5555555

    5555555 08:00 16:00
  987654321 08:00 16:00
```

As you can see, the material for John Smith was updated correctly, but the material for Jane Doe was unchanged.  This is correct given that there was no mapping for Jane.

---

For people not used to Informix: yes, you really can include DDL statements like CREATE TABLE inside a transaction, and yes, the created table really is rolled back if you roll back the transaction.  Not all DBMS are as generous as that.